# Editing the ckeditor config.js has no impact

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I changed my CKeditor config.js file to include all the buttons possible to this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'document', groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
        { name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
        { name: 'editing', groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker', 'editing' ] },
        { name: 'forms', groups: [ 'forms' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph', groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi', 'paragraph' ] },
        { name: 'links', groups: [ 'links' ] },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'insert' ] },
        '/',
        { name: 'styles', groups: [ 'styles' ] },
        { name: 'colors', groups: [ 'colors' ] },
        { name: 'tools', groups: [ 'tools' ] },
        { name: 'others', groups: [ 'others' ] },
        { name: 'about', groups: [ 'about' ] }
    ];
};
```

This config was generated using the CKeditor [config generator tool.](https://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/toolbarconfigurator/index.html#basic)

After the change was deployed to my server and the page was refreshed using incognito mode in chrome none of the buttons changed.

If I add this code directly in my `admin.master` then the new button does show.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
    });
</script>
```

Is it possible that I am not using the `config.js` at all?

Comment: CTRL-F5 to flush the browser cache?

Comment: yes did CTRL+F5 several times.

Comment: try to open config.js file in browser by typing its exact url and see if it has the updated code, if not refresh and then try to reload the page with ckeditor

Comment: Show us your initial config.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Github issue that was posted for this https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/pull/433 (a long time ago).
Also, a discussion post about unreflected changes when using `CKEDITOR.editorConfig` here: https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/config.js-changes-not-reflected

**My suggestion:**

Try to clear the cache after you change the config.
Check the "console" tab in your developpers inspector inside the browser to verify if there's is any errors.

As an alternative you could use the `replace()` method after destroying the loaded instance inside the `instanceReady` event callback like :

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.on("instanceReady", function(event) {
  CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy(); 
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
    toolbarGroups
  });
});
```

**[Working demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/8jscew96/48/).**

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I had to delete the browser data.   In Chrome you can select a time range.  At first, I selected the last hour and this didn't work.  Then I selected all times and it did.